# Ajax FileUpload

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, file-upload

Does a **fileuploader** can be done only with *ajax* and not with flash,jquery plugins or frames.

Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

No. You need some sort of server side code involved. JavaScript is client side and has no influence over what happens on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You must code the javascript by yourself, using XMLHTTPRequest and taking in account all the browser compatibility issue.

Of course you must write your server side code to manage the upload of the files. You must do this even with JQuery.

JQuery and other libraries are written to make the life of developer easy. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself. You say it is possible but then mention server side code.

Comment: The question is for the client side. For the client side it is possibile. Not for the server side part. Maybe a note on the question is appropriate?

Comment: Just have to point out that there is only **one** cross browser difference that can be fixed via `var xmlhttp = (!XMLHttpRequest) ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;`. When initialising the XMLHttpRequest object it will check if it exists, if not then it is IE and will use an ActiveXObject.

Comment: how do I submit a form with **multipart/form-data** using ajax